# Select specific columns from specific model morph relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to select only some columns from specifics morph models.

The withdrawal model:

```
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->morphTo('product', 'product_type', 'product_id');
    }
```

The Product1, Product2, and Product3 models has an ID and a name column. The Product4 and Product5 does not have the name column, so when I use the next code `->with('product:id,name')` it give me the error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found`

¿How can I select some specific column from specific models?

Comment: How can some Product instances don't not have `name` column, while others may have ? They are from the same table right ?

Comment: Nope. There is a Themes table, Audios, Videos, Photos... And every table has different columns, so from every model I want select specific columns.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a scope to the product models.

```
public function scopeFilter($query)
{
    return $query->select(['id', 'name', 'slug']);
}
```

Replace the array with your columns.

Then, in your `withdrawal` model, add the scope to the product relationship. Please make sure you have added the scope to all the potential product models.

```
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->morphTo('product', 'product_type', 'product_id')->filter();
    }
```